# Firebase sometimes doesn't trigger the onMessageReceived after a while if the app in the background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which uses the Firebase Functions. 
If the status of the app is not working or it is working in the foreground, there is no any problem. However, if it works in the background, sometimes, the onMessageReceived listener isn't triggered by the firebase. If I make the mobile phone active (leave it from the black screen), it starts to work correctly.

There is no any crash or error message, that's why I don't understand what the problem is. Is there any clue to solve this my issue?

Answer (score -2):

read in summary table: [Notiifcation documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)  that Notification in background will appear in tray, you can fix it by request from the back end server to send object `Data` instead of `Notification`

Comment: I am already using Notification. If I use the Data it never works in the bg. As I mentioned, It stops to work after a while if it works in the bg.

Comment: what you are calling on your notification receiver class, 
remoteMessage.getData() or remoteMessage.getNotification() ?
and please check with the Back end sender, if he using a custom json or the default one, i have faced same case and it solved by checking the json format from Notification sender in back end

Comment: I am using getData(). As I mentioned, It normally works in the background, foreground and even dead, but sometimes (the app is inactive) it doesn't work.